# how to pass a command line argument in the awk script

Tags: csv, awk

This type of question was asked before but not exactly this one. I am a rookie in bash and awk scripting. So I don't know how to full fill my goal.

My target is to generate sql insert from the csv file.

Here is my csv file contents:-

```
ID;NAME;AGE;TITLE;DATE;SALARY
1;Test1;36;Engineer;date '2022-10-12';50.40
2;Test2;45;Manager;date '2020-01-15';100.50
```

My awk script is sql.awk:-

```
    #!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
  FS=";"
  OFS=","
  quotation="'"
}
FNR==1 {
    $1=$1; head=$0
    next
}
{
  dat=""
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
      val=($i~/[[:alpha:]]$/)?quotation $i quotation:$i
      dat=(dat)?dat OFS val:val
  }
  printf("INSERT INTO  DATA ( %s) VALUES ( %s );\n", head, dat) > "data.sql"
}
END {
    print ENVIRON["strftime"] 
    printf("\n-- Generated by %s at %s\n", ENVIRON["USERNAME"], strftime("%Y-%m-%d %T")) >> "data.sql"
}
```

This script generates file data.sql with correct contents as:

```
  INSERT INTO  DATA ( ID,NAME,AGE,TITLE,DATE,SALARY) VALUES ( 
  1,'Test1',36,'Engineer',date '2022-10-12',50.40 );
  INSERT INTO  DATA ( ID,NAME,AGE,TITLE,DATE,SALARY) VALUES ( 
  2,'Test2',45,'Manager',date '2020-01-15',100.50 );

  -- Generated by usr_name at 2020-10-18 17:31:13
```

My target is to get the sql table name as a command-line argument. Instead of hardcode DATA, I want it from the command-line argument.

I tried to run this as where above sript is modified as:-

./sql.awk -f data.csv gievn_table_name

```
    #!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
  FS=";"
  OFS=","
  quotation="'"
  tableName=ARGV[2]
}
FNR==1 {
    $1=$1; head=$0
    next
}
{
  dat=""
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
      val=($i~/[[:alpha:]]$/)?quotation $i quotation:$i
      dat=(dat)?dat OFS val:val
  }
  printf("INSERT INTO  %s VALUES ( %s );\n",tableName, head, dat) > tableName.sql
}
END {
    print ENVIRON["strftime"] 
    printf("\n-- Generated by %s at %s\n", ENVIRON["USERNAME"], strftime("%Y-%m-%d %T")) >> tableName.sql
}
```

I got an error:

> ./sql.awk -f data.csv gievn_table_name
> awk: ./sql.awk:19:   printf("INSERT INTO  %s VALUES ( %s );\n",tableName, head, dat) > tableName.sql
> awk: ./sql.awk:19:                                                                              ^ syntax error
> awk: ./sql.awk:23:     printf("\n-- Generated by %s at %s\n", ENVIRON["USERNAME"], strftime("%Y-%m-%d %T")) >> tableName.sql
> awk: ./sql.awk:23:                                                                                                      ^ syntax error
> awk: data.csv:2: 1;Test1;36;Engineer;date '2022-10-12';50.40
> awk: data.csv:2:                          ^ invalid char ''' in expression
> awk: data.csv:2: 1;Test2;36;Engineer;date '2022-10-12';50.40
> awk: data.csv:2:                          ^ syntax error

How to get a command-line argument for the table name and output file name?

Comment: Database servers have built-in functions to load data from CSV, and you should use them instead of writing your own scripts that will likely be vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: To get the `tableName` to the script, use: `./csv2sql.awk -v tableName=gievn_table_name data.csv` and in the code you need to fix `> tableName ".sql"` (and then some).

Comment: Agree with advice to use `bcp` or other vendor supplied utility, but for your understanding, use the shell to pass command line args, Save above to myAwkScript, make script file with proper `#!/bin/bash` (or whichever) as first line, then call with `myAwkScript "$@"`. Call the `bash` script like `myBashAwker f1 f2 f3 .... fn`. Good luck.

Comment: Don't use a shebang to call the awk interpreter, it just makes your life harder. If you want a shell command to call, then use a shebang for your shell (e.g. `#!/usr/bin/env bash`) and then just call awk like you would from  the command line and if you want it to treat all arguments passed to the shell script as arguments for the awk script then add `"${@:--}"` at the end, i.e. `awk 'script' "${@:--}"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do `ARGC--` after reading a value from `ARGV` array if you don't want awk to process that as a file later. You may use:

```
cat sql.awk

BEGIN {
  FS=";"
  OFS=","
  quotation="'"
  tableName=ARGV[2]
  ARGC--
}
FNR==1 {
    $1 = $1
    head = $0
    next
}
{
  dat = ""
  for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
      val = ($i~/[[:alpha:]]$/) ? quotation $i quotation : $i
      dat = (dat != "") ? dat OFS val : val
  }
  printf("INSERT INTO %s ( %s ) VALUES ( %s );\n", tableName, head, dat)
}
END {
    printf("\n-- Generated by %s at %s\n", ENVIRON["USER"], strftime("%Y-%m-%d %T"))
}
```

To run this, use command:

```
awk -f sql.awk data.csv DATA
```

Alternatively, you can just use more common `-v tableName=DATA` to your awk command.

Comment: Also for testing, I updaed csv file and removed all single quotation '. Then i got this errro: `./test.awk -f data.csv tablename
awk: ./test.awk:5: fatal: cannot open file `tablename' for reading (No such file or directory)
`

Comment: @masiboo, stop using `-f` when you invoke your script. You're telling awk to process the csv file as an awk script.

Comment: @masiboo: To this this script use: `awk -f sql.awk data.csv DATA` where `sql.awk` is the script I have included in my answer.